# Ejecutar función javascript al final de todos los demás scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Quiero ejecutar un script al final de los demás scripts.

El detalle es que algunas funciones tardan en ejecutarse y no puedo leer las clases que generan, porque mi función se ejecuta antes que ellas.

Lo que hago es pegar mi función al final del documento, pero no funciona:

```
<script>
 function test(){
    alert ("test");
 }
 window.onload=test;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No importa el orden porque javascript es asíncrono.

Podrías utilizar la función then, ejecuta primero esa función y luego las instrucciones que quieras:

```
 function test(){
    alert ("test");
 }.then(
     //mis instrucciones
);
```

Saludos!